# Conda create and conda install

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have used anaconda and miniconda without problem before so I don't know why I am having doubts now about the order to use them as

1. create an environment with conda create
2. Activate the environment with conda activate
3. Install packages with conda install

However, lately I have read one set of instructions in which they do a different order:  1->3->2.  That means installing without activating and then activating.

Is this correct? Aren't I installing libraries outside of the environment?

Comment: If you include the `--name|-n` flag then it will install in the specific environment.

Comment: It depends on your needs. See my detailed explanation below

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple ways to create and install packages using conda.

- create an environment, activate, install packages

```sh
conda create --name env_name python=3.8
conda activate env_name
conda install package_name another_package
```

- create an environment with packages

```sh
conda create -n env_name python=3.8 package_name another_package
conda activate env_name
```

Both methods are correct. In fact, we often use a mix here and there. For example, if I have a project with requirements.txt to be installed with pip but would like it to have pandas and scikit-learn from conda-forge. I will do:

```sh
conda create --name ml_api python=3.7 -c conda-forge scikit-learn pandas
conda activate ml_api
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

At any point, we can add packages in conda environment with

```sh
# this will install requests to ml_api env. This can be done at any (env)
conda install --name ml_api requests
# or activate ml_api and install. This will install on activated env
conda activate ml_api
conda install requests
```

At the end of the day, conda is there to help you. A better flow will depend on your need.

Comment: I don't think the second option works: `conda: error: unrecognized arguments: scikit-learn pandas`. I'm using `conda 4.11.0`.

Comment: What is the advantage of using conda create and activate before conda install?

Comment: Because we want to install packages in the created environment. You do not have to activate before installing. You must pass environment name to install package in correct environment e.g. `conda install -n <my_created_env> <package name>`

Answer (score 0):

The order you listed them is correct but you only need the conda install packagename before you run the code. So you should first create the conda environment and then activate it. Now when you get ready to run the code the first time, be sure to install your package. This enables you to import the package in your python code.